# Cannot retrieve author in sidebar of single.php

Tags: sidebar, author

Within a post I can use `the_author()` to retrieve the author name, but in the sidebar of a single-post page this does not return anything. How to get metadata on the post author outside the post?

Comment: Be careful with those template tags. Some are intended for use inside the Loop and do not work reliably outside it. Check the Codex if aren't sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test whether on a single post. If so, get a user object by the current posts' author ID and echo its `display_name` property:

```
if ( is_single() ) {
    global $post;

    $author = get_userdata( $post->post_author );
    echo $author->display_name;
}
```